# In an API endpoint using Mongoose and MongoDB, how do I wait for all database queries to finish before returning a response to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing an API endpoint that calculates a user's total revenue for each day of the past 7 days.

I use the mongoose .find({}) method to query the database 8 times. After all 8 .find({}) calls return, I want to send a response to the client. Should I just chain all the .find({}) calls with .then functions which call the next .find({}), or is there a simpler way to wait for all queries to finish?

Here is what my route looks like minus a few of the .find({}) calls for the sake of brevity:

```
app.get('/loadThisWeeksRevenue/:userId', function(req, res, next) {

        //todays date info using momentjs
        var startOfToday = moment().startOf('day');
        var endOfToday = moment().endOf('day');
        var oneDayAgo = moment(startOfToday).subtract(1, 'days');
        var twoDaysAgo = moment(startOfToday).subtract(2, 'days');
        var threeDaysAgo = moment(startOfToday).subtract(3, 'days');
        var fourDaysAgo = moment(startOfToday).subtract(4, 'days');
        var fiveDaysAgo = moment(startOfToday).subtract(5, 'days');
        var sixDaysAgo = moment(startOfToday).subtract(6, 'days');
        var sevenDaysAgo = moment(startOfToday).subtract(7, 'days');

        //set variables for the past 7 days revenue
        var sevenDaysAgoRevenue = 0;
        var sixDaysAgoRevenue = 0;
        var fiveDaysAgoRevenue = 0;
        var fourDaysAgoRevenue = 0;
        var threeDaysAgoRevenue = 0;
        var twoDaysAgoRevenue = 0;
        var oneDayAgoRevenue = 0;
        var todaysRevenue = 0;


            //Calculate 7 days ago revenue
            Sale
            .find({ owner: req.params.userId, created_at: {$gte: sevenDaysAgo, $lt: sixDaysAgo} })
            .exec(function(err, sales) {

                if (err) { return next(err); } //check for error

                sales.map(sale => {
                    sevenDaysAgoRevenue += sale.total;
                });

            });

            //Calculate 6 days ago revenue
            Sale
            .find({ owner: req.params.userId, created_at: {$gte: sixDaysAgo, $lt: fiveDaysAgo} })
            .exec(function(err, sales) {

                if (err) { return next(err); } //check for error

                sales.map(sale => {
                    sixDaysAgoRevenue += sale.total;
                });

            });



            //Calculate 1 day ago revenue
            Sale
            .find({ owner: req.params.userId, created_at: {$gte: oneDayAgo, $lt: startOfToday} })
            .exec(function(err, sales) {

                if (err) { return next(err); } //check for error

                sales.map(sale => {
                    oneDayAgoRevenue += sale.total;
                });

            });

            //Calculate today's revenue
            Sale
            .find({ owner: req.params.userId, created_at: { $gte: startOfToday, $lt: endOfToday}})
            .exec(function(err, sales) {

                if (err) { return next(err); } //check for error

                sales.map(sale => {
                    todaysRevenue += sale.total;
                });

            });

            var dataRowsForWeeksRevenue = [
                [new Date(sevenDaysAgo), sevenDaysAgoRevenue],
                [new Date(sixDaysAgo), sixDaysAgoRevenue],
                [new Date(fiveDaysAgo), fiveDaysAgoRevenue],
                [new Date(fourDaysAgo), fourDaysAgoRevenue],
                [new Date(threeDaysAgo), threeDaysAgoRevenue],
                [new Date(twoDaysAgo), twoDaysAgoRevenue],
                [new Date(oneDayAgo), oneDayAgoRevenue],
                [new Date(), todaysRevenue]
            ];

            res.status(200).json(dataRowsForWeeksRevenue);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) package.

Example:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){ ... },
    function(callback){ ... }
], function(err, results) {
    // optional callback
};
```

In your case:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){ 

        Sale
        .find({ owner: req.params.userId, created_at: {$gte: sevenDaysAgo, $lt: sixDaysAgo} })
        .exec(function(err, sales) {

            if (err) { return callback(err); } //check for error

            sales.map(sale => {
                sevenDaysAgoRevenue += sale.total;
            });

            callback();
        });

},
    function(callback){ 
        Sale
        .find({ owner: req.params.userId, created_at: {$gte: sixDaysAgo, $lt: fiveDaysAgo} })
        .exec(function(err, sales) {

            if (err) { return callback(err); } //check for error

            sales.map(sale => {
                sixDaysAgoRevenue += sale.total;
            });

            callback();

        });

}
], function(err, results) {
    var dataRowsForWeeksRevenue = [
            [new Date(sevenDaysAgo), sevenDaysAgoRevenue],
            [new Date(sixDaysAgo), sixDaysAgoRevenue],
            [new Date(fiveDaysAgo), fiveDaysAgoRevenue],
            [new Date(fourDaysAgo), fourDaysAgoRevenue],
            [new Date(threeDaysAgo), threeDaysAgoRevenue],
            [new Date(twoDaysAgo), twoDaysAgoRevenue],
            [new Date(oneDayAgo), oneDayAgoRevenue],
            [new Date(), todaysRevenue]
        ];

        res.status(200).json(dataRowsForWeeksRevenue);
};
```

Comment: This worked. If I wanted to check for an error, would I add to the last function that takes err and results as paramaters, if (err) { res.status(400) }, or what would you recommend?

Comment: @Mjuice I've updated code to include errors, basically you just need to call callback(err) and on final function check if you got errors, if so res.status(400).send(err)

Comment: @AndrasDeak understood